# rank of matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

I have the following equation on entries of matrix $A$:
$$
H \, A \, H^T - H^2 \, A \, H^T H^T = 0.
$$
All matrices here are $n \times n$ matrices, so there are $n^2$ equations on $n^2$ variables. Is there any conditions (sufficient, necessary) on matrix $H$ for this system to have rank $n^2$? The same question about rank $n^2-1$.

UPD: Sorry, there was a typo in the original question: $n \to n^2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde First of all, sorry, there is a typo in the original question. I mean the following. If you expand indices of this equation, you will get a system of linear equations on entries of matrix $A$, i.e. $A_{ij}$. So, in a way, matrices $H$ here are coefficients and entries of $A$ are variables.

Comment: @DietrichBurde For instance, if $H$ is identity matrix, it is invertible, but the system of equations reduces to $0=0$, so its rank would be zero.

Comment: So the next case is, that $H$ is invertible. Then we have $A=HAH^T$, which has been studied, I believe.

Comment: @DietrichBurde would you be able to share the references where  this term $A=HAH^T$ has been studied?

Comment: It has been studied [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). The Sylvester equation $AX+XB=C$ is yours for $C=0$, $A=-H^{-1}$, $B=H^T$, and $X$ is your $A$ which we want to find.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the question, but it seems like a useful hint to me.

I find [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) useful for this problem.
For example, consider the case where the matrix $H$ is invertible.
Vectorization leads to the equation
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A)=(H\otimes H)\operatorname{vec}(A).
$$
That is, $\operatorname{vec}(A)$ is the eigenvector for $H\otimes H$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. By the way, the eigenvalues of $H\otimes H$ are numbers $\lambda_i\lambda_j$, where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $H$.

In the general case, the problem is a bit more complicated.

Comment: I agree : using vectorization and Kronecker product should be taught in every linear algebra course.

Answer (score 1):

The case where $H$ is invertible is the equation $H^{-1}A=AH^T$. This can be written as $H^{-1}X-XH^T=0$, which is a special case of the
"famous" [Sylvester matrix equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)
$$
AX+XB=C.
$$
This equation has been studied a lot, so I suppose that one can find suitable conditions on $H$ so that the system has full rank.